# What is the maximum number of rows retrieved in a SOQL NOT IN clause?

Tags: soql, limits, inner-join

What is the maximum number of rows, which can be queried **inside** a `NOT IN` clause? For example, let's say I have this query:

```
SELECT Id FROM Campaign WHERE Id NOT IN (
    SELECT xxx__campaign__c FROM xxx__data__c
)
```

Would the above query fail if an org has ten million records in the `xxx__data__c` object?

Comment: whatever its is ...(IN or Not IN) 10,000 rows only allowed. Otherwise you will end up with too many query rows

Comment: Check this out
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/105609/system-limitexception-too-many-query-rows-50001-even-though-soql-has-limit-10

Comment: Thanks, @bharath but there is nothing saying about the 10.000 row limit in a sub-query. I also tested it with more than 50.000 objects without any error.

Comment: @bharath Absolutely incorrect. Rows joined using `Left Inner Join` or `Left Anti Join` do not count against your query row limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`Left Anti Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Anti_Join) will definitely work with over one million records. In fact, I just ran a query with a `Left Anti Join` on ~4.2 million records and it executed successfully, though it did take a noticeable amount of time to run.

One problem you might face is query selectivity. If you investigate the `Query Plan` for such queries, you will find that they cause a `Table Scan`. So while it seems unlikely you will hit an upper bound on the number of rows included in the join, querying against a large table (>100k) in your top-level query might throw non-selective query errors for inner or anti joins.

One more consideration is that while your query processing time doesn't count against the CPU limit, you might increase the chance of timeouts if you connect this sort of query to a webservice or REST endpoint.

Comment: Thanks @adrian-larson. If I understand you correct (let's use my example) if there are only a few campaigns (around 1000) the query should be save?

Comment: @Detached Yes, that's certainly under 4.2M.